# vxworks 6.3 active sockets maxs out at 255?

Tags: sockets, reset, vxworks

I have a LPD server running on vxworks 6.3.  The client application (over which I have no control) is sending me a LPQ query every tenth of a second.  After 235 requests, the client receives a RST when trying to connect.  After a time device will again accept some queries (about 300), until it again starts sending out RST.

I have confirmed that it is the TCP stack that is causing the RST.  There are some things that I have noticed.

1) I can somewhat change the number of sockets that will accepted if I change the number of other applications that are running.  For example, I freed up 4 sockets thereby changing the number accepted from 235 to 239.
2) If I send requests to lpr (port 515) and another port (say, port 80), the total number of connections that are accepted before the RST start happening stays constant at 235.
3) There are lots of sockets sitting TIME_WAIT.
4) I have a mock version of the client.  If I slow the client down to one request every quarter second, the server doesn't reject the connections.
5) If I slow down the server's responses, I don't have any connections rejected.

So my theory is that there is some share resource (my top guess is total number of socket handles) that VxWorks can have consumed at a given time.  I'm also guessing that this number tops out at 255.

Does anyone know how I can get VxWorks to accept more connections, and leave them in TIME_WAIT when closed?  I have looked through the kernel configuration and changed all the values that looked remotely likely, but I have not been able change the number.

We know that we could set SO_LINGER but this not an acceptable solution.  However, this does prevent the client connections from getting rejected. We have also tried changed the timeout value for SO_LINGER.  This does not appear to be supported in VxWorks. It's either on or off.

Thanks!
Gail

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you are making a new connection for every LPQ query, and after the query is done you aren't closing the connection. In my opinion the correct thing to do is to accept one TCP connection and then use that to get all of the LPQ queries, however that may require mods to the client application. To avoid mods to the client, you should just close the TCP connection after each LPQ query.

Furthermore you can set the max number of FDs open in vxworks by adjusting the #define NUM_FILES config.h (or configall.h or one of those files), but that will just postpone an error if you have a FD leak, which you probably do.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the advise.  We don't actually have leak; all connections are closed when we are done with them.  The socket will leave the TIME_WAIT after...1 minute.  The TCP stack is keeping the socket open waiting for delayed network traffic. I did try changing NUM_FILES, but that didn't seem to change the behavior.  Luckily we convinced the customer to change their application to query less often which allows us to avoid the entire problem.